# TypeError: cannot read/set property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, batterylevel

I was trying to show battery level using javascript where I found an unexpected error.
My codes:

```
const  percentage = document.getElementById('percentage');
const percent = document.getElementById('percent');
navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery){
                percentage.style.width = battery.level * 100 + '%' ;
                percent.innerHTML = battery.level * 100  + '%';
                alert(battery.level);
});
```

I got an error saying, >TypeError: cannot read the proper 'style' of null
When I try putting the 4th and 5th line on the comment
e.g.

```
// 
  percentage.style.width = battery.level * 100 + '%' ;
```

First, I got another error message saying:

> TypeError: Cannot set the property 'innerHTML' of null
> Then, the alert() gave the correct battery level

Comment: Hi, Try using something like: `const  percentage = document.getElementById('percentage')[0];`

Comment: @YashMaheshwari It won't work since `getElementById` returns the first element that matches the given id, not an array.

Comment: Make sure there is an element with an id="percentage" on the DOM when the code executes.
You can also try document.querySelector("#percentage")

Comment: I was sure about my html contents, I faced the problem in thr javascript, but I have solved it by my own. Thank you very much for your response

Answer (score 0):

I have found it's solution. Instead of using variables, I wrote the whole statement before .style and that worked.
Final code:

```
                            setInterval(function(){ navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery){
                document.getElementById('percentage').style.width = battery.level * 100 + '%' ;
                document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = battery.level * 100  + '%';
});
}, 10);
```